# Add bootstrap class to wp_list_pages()?

Tags: wordpress

I have a bootstrap navbar and its items must generate by wordpress wp_list_pages() method.After running this method items have another class .I want to give them bootstrap classes.
What whould I do for this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Following the code of the [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) function, you'll see the function relies on [Walkers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/) to build the list items, and uses filters to extend its functionality.

So, you can either create your own `Walker` extending [`Walker_Page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_page/), or add a filter to the [`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_pages/) and [`page_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/) hooks to manipulate the output strings to add your classes like so:

```php
/**
 * Add class to menu.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_pages/
 */
function so52918879_wp_list_pages( string $output, array $parsed_args, array $pages ): string {
    return str_replace( 'class="pagenav"', 'class="pagenav nav"', $output );
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_pages', 'so52918879_wp_list_pages', 10, 3 );
```

```php
/**
 * Add class to menu item.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_css_class/
 */
function so52918879_page_css_class( array $css_classes, WP_Post $page, int $depth, array $args, int $current_page ): array {
    $css_classes[] = 'nav-item';
    return $css_classes;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'so52918879_page_css_class', 10, 5 );
```

The above code is not tested, and you may need to adjust it a bit by adding validations, and add the classes you need.